# declare variables in the same line shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below is a part of my script where I used different lines for different variable.In the first two lines command used is similar though not same , is there a way to reduce these five lines:

```
oldv=$( sed -n "${c}p" ~/grepoutput | awk '{print $3 }')
     line=$(sed -n "${c}p" ~/grepoutput | awk -F":" '{print $2 }')
     newv=$( sed -n "${c}p" ~/vpkglist | awk '{print $3 }' )
     oldr=$( sed -n "${c}p" ~/vpkglist | awk '{print $4 }' )
     newr=$( sed -n "${c}p" ~/vpkglist | awk '{print $5 }' )
```

In the first two lines it`s 'grepoutput' is the same file and bottom three lines 'vpkglist' remains same.

Comment: looks like you can't

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with them afterwards. Potentially, this could be a single awk script.

Comment: Add content of $c to your question.

Comment: `read newv oldr newr < <(awk "${c}"'{print $3,$4,$5}' ~/vpkglist)` might do the last three lines, but as @Cyrus says, we really need to know the value of `$c`.  It could be that the `awk` interpreter is not needed at all.